# Huffman tree pointer point to unexpected location

Tags: c++, pointers, data-structures, out-of-memory, huffman-code

I am stuck on a Huffman Tree problem. I think my code has a clear logic. I first built a priority queue to compare the weight of Node and place the Node with minimum weight at the top of the priority queue.

```
#include<iostream>
#include<vector>
#include<queue>
using namespace std;

struct Node
{
    int weight, depth;
    Node *left, *right;
    Node(int value):weight(value), left(NULL),right(NULL),depth(0){}
    Node(int value, Node* left_leaf_ptr, Node* right_leaf_ptr) : weight(value), left(left_leaf_ptr), right(right_leaf_ptr), depth(0) {}
};

//this struct is used for priority queue
struct Greater
{  
    bool operator () (Node a, Node b){return a.weight > b.weight;}
};

// find whether the node is a leaf
bool isleaf(Node node) { return node.left == NULL && node.right == NULL; }

// update the depth of Huffman Tree
void update_depth(Node& node,int depth)
{
    node.depth=depth;
    if (! isleaf(node))
    {
        depth++;
        update_depth(*node.left,depth);
        update_depth(*node.right, depth);
    }
}

Node build_Huffman_tree(priority_queue<Node, vector<Node>, Greater> weights_queue)
{
    while (weights_queue.size() > 1)
    {
        Node l1=weights_queue.top();
        weights_queue.pop();
        Node l2 = weights_queue.top();
        weights_queue.pop();
        Node l3(l1.weight + l2.weight, &l1, &l2);
        update_depth(l3, 0);
        weights_queue.push(l3);
    }
    return weights_queue.top();
}

int main()
{
    priority_queue<Node, vector<Node>, Greater> weights_queue;
    weights_queue.push(Node(1));
    weights_queue.push(Node(1));
    weights_queue.push(Node(3));
    weights_queue.push(Node(5));
    Node root = build_Huffman_tree(weights_queue);
    return 0;
}
```

When I run this program in C++ 11, in the second while loop inside the function build_Huffman_tree, it creates a Node of weight 2, depth 4700. What's worse is that this Node seems endless. i.e. its left child tree has weight 2, and this child tree has its left child tree of weight 2, and so on...

So please point out the reason of my program's failure and teach me how to fix it.

Comment: Have you tried using a debugger?

Comment: Yes, I've tried of course.

Comment: priority_queue should works with add and remove - check if pop actually remove the node from the queue (the behavior you describe sound like the lowest node never been extract from the queue)